# Issue with TreeView in an ASP.NET master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

If I click the treeview in master page's leftside menu, the file should open in contect place holder (main). Below is my code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView1" runat="server">
                    <Nodes>
                        <asp:TreeNode Expanded="True" Text="Sample Links" Value="Sample Links">
                            <asp:TreeNode NavigateUrl="~/one.htm" Target="fmain" Text="First Node"
                                Value="First Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                            <asp:TreeNode NavigateUrl="~/two.htm" Target="fmain" Text="Second Node"
                                Value="Second Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                            <asp:TreeNode NavigateUrl="~/three.htm" Target="fmain" Text="Third Node"
                                Value="Third Node"></asp:TreeNode>
                        </asp:TreeNode>
                    </Nodes>
                </asp:TreeView>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="tmain" runat="server">
                </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't really do that directly. Closest thing is using `iframe` inside the `asp:ContentPlaceHolder` give it name then assign `target` to the tree node links..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master pages were designed for page inheritance, not as a page to load other pages. What you should be doing is using aspx pages which inherit from the master page.

Here are some guides on them:
http://www.asp.net/master-pages/tutorials

If you really must load in html files I suggest using an iframe or opening them in a new window.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Here goes the code that process the TreeView1.SelectedNode to get the appropriate URL");
}
```